# poker probability with 5 cards with opponent

Tags: probability

A player at draw poker holds the seven of spades and the eight, nine,
ten, and ace of diamonds. Aware that all the other players are drawing three cards, he figures that any hand he could win with a flush he could also win with a straight. For which should he draw?

Comment: If we were to ignore the fact that the other players exist at all and imagine their cards shuffled back into the deck, it sounds as though you are asking whether it is more likely to complete a flush or if you are more likely to complete a straight.  If you toss the spade, how many cards give you the flush?  If you toss the ace, how many cards give you the straight?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, we want to know whether it is more likely to draw a straight or a flush. To get a straight, he would get rid of the ace of diamonds and hope for either a six or a jack. There are four suits, so there would be $2*4=8$ different ways to get a straight. To get a flush, he must discard the seven of spades and hope for a diamond. There are $13$ diamonds and he currently has $4$ of them, so there are $13-4=9$ ways to get a flush. Since there are more ways to get a flush than a straight, he should try to get a flush.

Note that we have no idea what the opponent's cards are so there is no reason to take them into consideration, especially if we don't care about the resulting value of the hand, just that it be either a straight or a flush.

Answer (score 0):

The odds are better on a flush (9 "hit" cards versus 8), and the flush draw  has another tiny advantage:  If you draw an Ace, you might take the pot if nobody else improves her pair.